# how to convert RubyXL workbook to binary in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, binary, rubyxl

I used gem RubyXL to export something to a workbook,
and I do not want to use `workbook.write()` to create a file,
but want to save the workbook to mysql DB as binary.

how can i convert the **RubyXL workbook** to **binary**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution just now it is

> workbook.stream.read